# If someone is on my "Close friends" list on Facebook, will I get notified when they post on a non-friend's wall?

Tags: facebook, friend-list

If a "close friend" posts on someone's wall (that isn't my friend) will I still get a notification?

Comment: No, but it may appear in wall

Answer (score 2):

You will only be notified when a `close friend` interacts with their own timeline in the following ways:

- They posting a status update
- Post a photo
- Checkin
- Update their profile picture

You can turn on/off these notifications via the [instructions here](https://www.facebook.com/help/112320895539157/)

Answer (score 0):

No, you get notifications only when a close friend posts on their own wall.